# Is it possible to register events with nginx's event loop?

Tags: nginx, event-driven, libuv, hiredis

I want a web server based on `nginx`, which receives a HTTP message, parses it and checks in `Redis` for a given key's value and send back a response, all this has to be done asynchronously / non-blocking read/write from `Redis`.

Is it possible? I went through articles which suggested to register events to `nginx`'s loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ngx_lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and the associated [redis library](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis).

These are designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: let me look into that

Comment: @melvin_jose Not sure what you mean. These are tools that can be used to  take a HTTP message, parse it and check in Redis for a given key's value and send back a response which is what you say you want to do. You have to write up the logic in the same way a spade is a tool that can be used to create a trench but you will need to do the digging.

Comment: how to they make it non-blocking ?

Comment: You will have to ask the author of the module or look into the source code and figure that out yourself. I have pointed you to the solution to your query and not sure what the relevance of the follow up question is as long as  the tools solve your issue.

Comment: i tried contacting the author, no replies till now, and going through the code is very difficult as there is no documentation for those modules. Sorry, for delaying the bounty award, just wanted to make sure that this was the right one.